# How can a question be asked by the Community user?

Tags: support, community-user

When searching for the [nuitka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuitka) tag on Stack Overflow, [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47017032/2675154) asked by Community is shown:

> [image: Screenshot of the search result]

However, when I open the question, I can see that it was asked by *user8236453*:

> [image: Screenshot of the question]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Posts of users who leave the site via deletion, are "owned" by the Community user.

Comment: Still the difference is strange between the search and the actual post ...

Comment: @testing To make in consistent, I think it should also say _Community_ inside the actual question instead of _user8236453_.

Comment: @Skipper: Yes, that would make sense.

Comment: @Skipper That would make it hard to know if a comment is from, for example, the author of a post or someone else with a deleted account.

Comment: @testing Difference is strange, and it would make more sense if it just said "Deleted user"

Comment: @Laurel _Dead man tells no tales_ :)

Comment: It should show both something like  "asked Oct 30 '17 at 13:55 community (*user8236453*)"